# GORM mapping - View Create Statement

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an Domain Class that is mapped on a Database View like this:

```
static mapping = {
   table 'view_foo'
}
```

If I start the project and the view doesn't exist there will be a table named `view_foo`.

How can I let hibernate create the Database View?

I would like to set an SQL Statement that will be run to instead of the hibernate generated statement, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Grails Database Migration Plugin. This runs before Hibernate is initialized. It even allows to use native SQL queries.